# create react app with apollo client doesn't get any response

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) with [apollo client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and I followed the coding which is on [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html).
My server is configured [apollo server with express](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/servers/express.html) and I tested it followed the [GraphQL Clients](http://graphql.github.io/graphql-js/graphql-clients/) way. It works but when I tried to use [apollo client way](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html) It doesn't work. Here's my code.

In index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: `/graphql`
});

ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><App /></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

- I already tried to change uri such as `http://localhost:4000/graphql` or `http://localhost:4000`

in App.js file

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query} from 'react-apollo';

const callQuery = gql`
{ 
  hello 
}
`;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const test = this.HelloApi();
    console.log(test);
  }

  HelloApi() {
    <Query query={callQuery}>
      {({loading, error, data}) => {
        if(error) return `Error!: ${error}`;

        return data;
      }}
    </Query>
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I couldn't get any response via console and web. Please let me know what I'm missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to test a query in a lifecycle method I would use the higher order component "withApollo"

[#withApollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#withApollo)

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {Query, withApollo} from 'react-apollo';

const callQuery = gql`
{ 
  hello 
}
`;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
  componentDidMount() {
    const test = this.props.client.query({ query: callQuery })
    console.log(test);
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(App);
```

by doing this, you will have access to the client in the lifecycle method "componentDidMount()"

you can do:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const test = this.props.client.query({ query: callQuery })
    console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I figured it out to solve my problem via your tips.
It's not perfectly same way, but it helped to see another methods.

Comment: No problem. The query component you used, usually is used in the render method. you can console log within the query component. 

`<Query query={callQuery}>
      {({loading, error, data}) => {
        if(error) return `Error!: ${error}`;
        console.log(data)
        return data;
      }}
    </Query>`